# Is it safe to set parts of a NuGet package version number to greater than 65535?

Tags: .net, nuget

NuGet 1.4 is allowing packages to be created with part of the version number greater than 65535 (i.e. 1.0.0.1000000)

Are there any technical reasons to avoid using large numbers for parts of the package version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though unusual, I don't see a technical issue not to do this. NuGet uses System.Version for its versions, and that uses ints for the 4 numbers, so I'd say anything up to Int32.MaxValue is usable.

[SemVer](http://semver.org/) also just states that the values are integers, so I don't think those high numbers violate that (though technically, using 4 numbers is not correct for SemVer, but that's orthogonal).